# How to use SSDT to compare database with different default schema

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, database-schema, sql-server-data-tools

I have two database that belongs to two different SQL Server. Their database schema should be very similar but somehow different application generate different 'default schema' on the tables and views. Now when I am trying to compare the schema by using SSDT, I don't know how to ignore this default schema (I found it has a setting but it didn't value, same result showing as treating them as different set of objects).

e.g. Database A  vs Database B
[dbuser].[TableA]   vs  [dbo].[TableA]

SSDT claims they are different..... :S

Please give me some advice... I expect I don't have to hack the database in order to achieve the comparison....

Comment: Well, technically they are different because they're in different schemas. You may want to look at moving objects to the same schema if at all possible and changing your users to have the same default schema as well (likely "dbo" unless you have other requirements). Once you get that cleared up, you can use schema compare with much more ease.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the headache get sql-compare from redgate. You shoukd be able to get a trial and test your scenaior.  This tool plus their SQL toolbelt is a must for anyone dealing with multiple sql servers. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Comment: Personally I can't deny more.... but our company is kind of trying to leverage different reuse value of tools, and SSDT can be one of the plus for going VS Premium+ or not...